# How correctly to use external files in Spring MVC?

Tags: java, spring, file, spring-mvc

I can't access files that are not stored in `src/main/` project path

**Project structure:** 
[image: Project tree]

Now I can access all files from `webapp/resources` but can't access files from userResources folder

**Spring resourceHandler:**

```
@EnableWebMvc
@Configuration
public class AppConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {
 //some configs

   @Override
   public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
       registry.addResourceHandler("/resource/**").addResourceLocations("/resources/");
       registry.addResourceHandler("/vendors/**").addResourceLocations("/vendors/");
       //this line won't work
       registry.addResourceHandler("/userResources/**").addResourceLocations(
        "home/pika/workspace/Spring/Bookmarks/userResources")
       );
   }
}
```

In view

```
<img class="fb-image-lg" src="/home/pika/workspace/Spring/Bookmarks/userResources/admin/profile/wallImage.png" alt="Profile wall image" align="left">
```

**Image not found**, I try to change src with: "/userResources/admin/profile/wallImage.png" anyway it doesn't work

```
<img class="fb-image-profile thumbnail" src="/resources/images/defaultProfilePhoto.png" alt="Profile face image" align="left">
```

**Found image.**

What I'm doing wrong?

**PS** [Github repo](https://github.com/gvart/Bookmarks) may it helps you to understand project structure

Comment: Where is your view file(html/jsp) located?

Comment: @RohitGaikwad webapp/WEB-INF/views/user/profile.jsp

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The resource location `"home/pika/workspace/Spring/Bookmarks/userResources"` is looked for inside the web app, not on the file system (just like the other starting with "/resources"). To target the file system, use a file URL:

```
file:/home/pika/workspace/Spring/Bookmarks/userResources
```

This is however a terrible idea: the web server where you'll deploy that application doesn't have the same directory structure as the one you have on your developer machine. You should include these resources inside the webapp. Or store these images in your database. Or on the file system, but then at least with an externalized based directory, that isn't hard-coded like this in the code.

Comment: Thanks, for answer, It's not harcoded, I list few code like this to explain logic.  ``Folder path`` is stored in a editable ``properties file``. I read some posts that recommend to save user files in external directories, out of project, anyway thanks for recommendations

Comment: If it's data, coming from the users of your app, then it should definitely be out of the app. On the file system, in a database, or in an external storage service.